# GCDAsyncUdpSocket Time out

Tags: iphone, ios, udp, timeout, asyncsocket

In my application I am using `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` for UDP Packet communication...

I have written the code like the below

```
GCDAsyncUdpSocket* UDPSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

 [UDPSocket sendData:dataForSendToServer toHost:stringForHostId port:portNumber withTimeout:5 tag:1];
```

I like to use the Timeout property to resend the Packet again if packet has timed out...

In `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` API Document it says

```
The timeout for the send opeartion. If the timeout value is negative, the send operation will not use a timeout."
```

So the Timeout with -1 will work to automatically resend the packets?..or any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your understanding of timeout was reversed.  Here is the quote from the author's doc "If the timeout value is negative, the send operation will not use a timeout."  So to do what you planed, you will need to use a positive value.  And you can implement to resend logic in the timeout callback method:

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didNotSendDataWithTag:(long)tag dueToError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Thanks friend,I understood.So negative Timeout is not to resend the packet,just to send the packet without any timeout and I should use didNotSendDataWithTag delegate method to resend the packet if any errors like GCDAsyncUdpSocketSendTimeoutError occurs.